# Injectivity and surjectivity of $\lambda I-A$.

Tags: operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let us $A$ a square matrix, $\lambda\in \mathbb R^+$, $I$ identity matrix, R a operator, X Banach space.

If
$$(\lambda I-A) Ru=u \ \ (u\in X)$$
and
$$R(\lambda I-A) u=u \ \ (u\in X)$$

then can we obtain that $\lambda I-A$ is one-to-one and onto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $R$ is also a square matrix and $X$ is just finite-dimensioned space. Let $B=(\lambda I-A)$. If I understand correctly, the first equation holds for $\forall u$, which implies that $\det BR\ne 0$, therefore $\det B\ne 0$, which gives that $B$ is injective and surjective.

Comment: and what is it for the second hypothesis?

Comment: @Mark I don't need it. The first hypothesis essentially says that $B=R^{-1}$, but left and right inverse matrices coincide, therefore the second equation is a consequence of the first one.